# C dll return a wrong value in C# wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pinvoke

**Upadte:** I found it's just happened when i was use **.net framework 3.5** or less but i should be use **.net framework 3.5**.

I have a **c DLL** that's analyze my file.

I wrote a C# **Windows Form** that's open file and send file path to my DLL and show result.
I need to use WPF and wrote a same **WPF** without any changes in my code. **But** the DLL return wrong result.

I searching in web but i can't found any answer.

Windows Form code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string cascade_name_face = "cascade_name_face.xml";
        static string cascade_name_face2 = "cascade_name_face2.xml";

        [DllImport("aref_video_score", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern double aref_video_score(String fileName, int a, String cascade_name_face, String cascade_name_face2);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "All file|*.*";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Address1.Text = dlg.FileName;
            }
        }


        private double video_analyze(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                return aref_video_score(filename, 20, cascade_name_face, cascade_name_face2);
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;
            };
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsVideo(Address1.Text))
                MessageBox.Show("This is a 'Video' and video's scroe is " + video_analyze(Address1.Text).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

WPF code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static string cascade_name_face = "cascade_name_face.xml";
        static string cascade_name_face2 = "cascade_name_face2.xml";

        [DllImport("aref_video_score", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern double aref_video_score(String fileName, int a, String cascade_name_face, String cascade_name_face2);

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();



            // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
            dlg.Filter = "All file|*.*";


            // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();


            // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
            if (result == true)
            {
                // Open document 
                string filename = dlg.FileName;
                Address1.Text = filename;
            }
        }

       private double video_analyze(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                return aref_video_score(filename, 20,cascade_name_face, cascade_name_face2);
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;
            };
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                if(IsVideo(Address1.Text))
                    MessageBox.Show("This is a 'Video' and video's scroe is " + video_analyze(Address1.Text).ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "dll return wrong result"?

Comment: Is it the DLL that's returning incorrectly, or **video_analyze** that's returning -1? Try removing the catch block in **video_analyze**   in and see if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The p/invoke code is handled in exactly the same way in a all .net applications. So, clearly the difference between the two programs lies elsewhere. Some possible reasons include:

1. The programs are finding different versions of the native DLL.
2. The programs are using different versions of the two XML files.
3. The p/invoke declaration is incorrect somehow and a change of .net version and/or operating system happens to highlight the error in one program but not the other.

To track this down you should work hard to isolate exactly what of the many differences between the two applications triggers the behaviour change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct string type in your DLLImport?
you should specify ANSI or Unicode using

```
CharSet=Ansi
```

or

```
CharSet=Unicode
```

in the DLLImport attribute. see this [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: It's the same in both programs